# CUDA, MySQL, and CMake

Tags: mysql, cuda, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm trying to create a CUDA program (which I'm new at) that involves first grabbing information from a remote MySQL database. I'm using the Connector/C library from the MySQL website inside the program, before the CUDA calls.

I'm able to compile my program with MySQL when using gcc (without any CUDA code), but not with nvcc (the CUDA compiler). A peer who is familiar with CUDA mentioned to me that he had to compile some libjpg stuff he was doing with nvcc to avoid 'wrong architecture' and linking problems. He suggested that I compile the Connector/C library with nvcc. However, the Connector/C library uses CMake instead of a regular Makefile.

So, being new to CMake, I researched some stuff and found the toolchain file which sounded a lot like what I needed (found here). However, I am running into problems during the compile where all of the default includes and libraries used in Connector/C are not included. Specifically

```
-- Looking for include files HAVE_ALLOCA_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_ALLOCA_H - not found.
```

and

```
-- Looking for strstr
-- Looking for strstr - not found
```

Those are just a couple examples, there are many more files that are not found.
Am I approaching this problem correctly? Is there a more obvious workaround that I am just not considering? If I am right in trying to compile MySQL Connector/C with CUDA, are there any suggestions for properly including the files and libraries required for Connector/C?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know much about this, and I didn't write my project's Makefile. But, for what it's worth, a quick look at my Makefile shows me that we use nvcc for code with kernels in it and for linking, while we use gcc for the other code. ie, have you tried compiling the MySQL code with gcc, but linking with nvcc?

Answer (score 1):

If you can separate out the CUDA kernels from your mysql calls and place them in separate files, you can use your Makefile.

I keep all of the cuda kernels and such in .cu files and then I have a definition:

```
#
# CUDA Compilation Rules
#

define cuda-compile-rule
  $1: $(call generated-source,$2) \
    $(call source-dir-to-build-dir, $(subst .cu,.cubin, $2)) \
    $(call source-dir-to-build-dir, $(subst .cu,.ptx, $2))
    $(NVCC) $(CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -o $$@ -c $$<

  $(call source-dir-to-build-dir, $(subst .cu,.cubin, $2)): $(call generated-source,$2)
    $(NVCC) -cubin -Xptxas -v $(CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<

  $(call source-dir-to-build-dir, $(subst .cu,.ptx, $2)): $(call generated-source,$2)
    $(NVCC) -ptx $(CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<
endef
```

I've also included three functions for ease of use:

```
generated-source = $(filter %.cpp, $1) $(filter %.c, $1) $(filter %.f, $1) $(filter %.F, $1) $(filter %.cu, $1)
source-dir-to-build-dir = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $1)
source-to-object = $(call source-dir-to-build-dir, \
           $(subst .f,.o,$(filter %.f,$1)) \
           $(subst .F,.o,$(filter %.F,$1)) \
           $(subst .c,.o,$(filter %.c,$1)) \
           $(subst .cpp,.o,$(filter %.cpp,$1)) \
           $(if $(filter 1,$(USE_CUDA)),$(subst .cu,.cu.o,$(filter %.cu,$1))))
```

Then all you need to do is build up a list of source files and call:

```
$(foreach f,$(filter %.cu, $listOfFiles),$(call cuda-compile-rule,$(call source-to-object,$f),$f))
```

Note that in the function `source-to-object` there is a variable which I use to conditionally disable CUDA compilation `USE_CUDA`.

Comment: This seems a bit overwhelming.  I'll look at it and see what I can come up with.  I'm just not familiar with the behavior of makefiles I guess.  Thanks for your response and I will try and get back to this soon.